# How to link to a Facebook page which isn't about the app?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-page

I installed the Facebook plugin on my WordPress site and, since it requires a Facebook app to work, I created one. The purpose of this app is only to integrate the WordPress site with Facebook. Now, I have a Facebook Fan page for the site, but I can't find a way to relate it to the app, unless I change it to an app page (which it isn't, I only created the app for the plugin to work). It is as if the Fan Page was completely unrelated from the site, because the app makes no relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything to do with the app page.

What you need is to get [the app id and its secret key](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) in order to fill the corresponding forms under the plugin configuration.

Please follow the [installation guide](https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/).